# Magento "301 Moved Permanently"

Tags: magento

We have moved our site from on server to another but after that i am receiving the message "301 Moved Permanently
nginx/1.9.11" And in case of admin i am getting 404 error. Anybody have any idea about this issue? Please help me. Thanks

FrameWork = Magento 1.9.1.0 Community Edition 
OS = Ubuntu
LAMP

Comment: You'll need to provide much more information before anyone can help. Most importantly at this stage, IMO, What does your current nginx config look like?

Comment: I am using Magento 1.9.1.0 community edition And LAMP. Can you please let me know what other information do you need?

Comment: The message is from nginx. So if you're running a LAMP stack then I'm guessing you have apache running behind nginx and nginx is just used as a reverse proxy to Apache but you would need to speak to whomever is responsible for sysadmin and understand what your deployment looks like.

Comment: Actually i am copying it from client server to my local server. I have found the reason of admin url. Admin path was different from the front name set in the app/etc/local.xml it was set through setting which we can found in app_config_data table where the path value is 'admin/url/custom_path';

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We are using the Magento framework. We have bought some modules. Some of them can work for a specific domain agaisnt which we bought it. As when we move the site from one server to another. So one of the third party module was creating this message. In our case the module was MD_Productpdf.